# Organizar arquivo Json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Eu queria um jeito de organizar este arquivo Json:

```
{
    "ajuda": {
        "name":"Ajuda",
        "category": "Sistema",
        "desc":"Mostra todos os comandos disponiveis.",
        "usage":"ajuda [grupo ou comando]"
    },  
    "ping": {
        "name":"Ping",
        "category": "Sistema",
        "desc":"Usado para saber a latencia do bot.",
        "usage":"ping"
    },  
    "status": {
        "name":"Status",
        "category": "Sistema",
        "desc":"Mostra algumas estatística úteis do bot.​",
        "usage":"status"
    },
    "convidar": {
        "name":"Convidar",
        "category": "Miscelânea",
        "desc":"Usado para mostrar o meu link de convite.",
        "usage":"convidar"
    },
    "kick": {
        "name":"Kick",
        "category": "Administração",
        "desc":"Usado para expulsar a pessoa mencionada.",
        "usage":"kick <@user>"
    }


}
```

Em ordem alfabetica por categoria. E encaixar ele nesse codigo aqui:

```
let currentCategory = "";
        let output = `= Lista de Comandos =\n\n[Use ${config.prefix}ajuda <comandos> para detalhes]\n`;


        for (var cmd in commands) {

                const cat = commands[cmd].category;
                  if (currentCategory !== cat) {
                output += `\u200b\n== ${cat} ==\n`;
                    currentCategory = cat;
                  }

                  output += `${config.prefix}${commands[cmd].name} :: ${commands[cmd].desc}\n`


        }


        message.channel.send(output, {code: "asciidoc", split: { char: "\u200b" }});
```

Mas eu não etou conseguindo... Ja tentei de 300 jeitos que achei na internet mas nada.

Comment: Ordenar alfabeticamente mas por categoria. Entao quero que ele coloque todos da categoria administração primeiro, depois todos da categoria miscelânea e de pois todos da categoria sistema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma vez que se trata de um objeto e não um array tem de fazer a ordenação pelas chaves. Para obter as chaves pode utilizar o [método `keys` de Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) passando os comandos como parâmetro. Depois ordena as chaves utilizando o método [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) no qual especifica a ordenação pela categoria.

Exemplo:

```js
const json = `{
    "ajuda": {
        "name":"Ajuda",
        "category": "Sistema",
        "desc":"Mostra todos os comandos disponiveis.",
        "usage":"ajuda [grupo ou comando]"
    },  
    "ping": {
        "name":"Ping",
        "category": "Sistema",
        "desc":"Usado para saber a latencia do bot.",
        "usage":"ping"
    },  
    "status": {
        "name":"Status",
        "category": "Sistema",
        "desc":"Mostra algumas estatística úteis do bot.​",
        "usage":"status"
    },
    "convidar": {
        "name":"Convidar",
        "category": "Miscelânea",
        "desc":"Usado para mostrar o meu link de convite.",
        "usage":"convidar"
    },
    "kick": {
        "name":"Kick",
        "category": "Administração",
        "desc":"Usado para expulsar a pessoa mencionada.",
        "usage":"kick <@user>"
    }
}`;

let comandos = JSON.parse(json);

//ordenação por category
let chavesOrdenadas = Object.keys(comandos).sort(
    (a,b) => comandos[a].category.localeCompare(comandos[b].category)
);

for (let chave of chavesOrdenadas){
    console.log(comandos[chave]);
}
```

A ordenação foi feita consultando a categoria do comando em `comandos[a].category` e depois utilizando [`localeCompare` da `String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) para fazer a comparação entre categorias.

A partir deste momento apenas tem que utilizar as chaves ordenadas sempre que quiser fazer alguma operação sobre os comandos todos.

Aplicando no seu `for` ficaria assim:

```
let orderedCommands = Object.keys(commands).sort(
    (a,b) => commands[a].category.localeCompare(commands[b].category)
);

for (let cmd of orderedCommands /*<--aqui as chaves ordenadas*/) {
    const cat = commands[cmd].category;
    if (currentCategory !== cat) {
        output += `\u200b\n== ${cat} ==\n`;
        currentCategory = cat;
    }

    output += `${config.prefix}${commands[cmd].name} :: ${commands[cmd].desc}\n`;
}
```

Comment: Opa! Gostei muito da sua resposta e me ajudou a solucionar o problema! Mas, quando fui aplicar no meu `for` tive que substituir na minha estrutura de repetição o `var` por `let` e o `in` por `of`. Igual no seu primeiro exemplo.

Comment: @Henrique Sim, ainda bem que me avisa, de facto é mesmo necessário que itere as *keys* com `for .. of` ou `for` normal